# ayuda con una calculadora hecha en javascript y HTML

Tags: html

Estaba siguiendo un tutorial para hacer una calculadora en HTML y javascript y no sé en qué me equivoqué ya que seguí todos los pasos del video.

este es el código de HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title> Calculadora Basica en javascript </title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

<style>

input[type=button],input[type="text"]{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 font-size: 30px; 
}
table,form{
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

</style> 



</head>

<body>
<form name="Fo">
<table>
 <tr>
    <td colspan="5"><input type="text" name="valores" id="valores" onkeypress="return"></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="7" onClick="retornar(value)"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="8" onClick="retornar(value)"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="9" onClick="retornar(value)"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="+"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="-"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="4" onClick="retornar(value)"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="5" onClick="retornar(value)"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="6" onClick="retornar(value)"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="*"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="/"></td>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="1" onClick="retornar(value)"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="2" onClick="retornar(value)"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="3" onClick="retornar(value)"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="<-"></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="C"></td>
    </tr>
</tr>
<tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="0" onClick="retornar(value)"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="="></td>
    </tr>


</table>    


</form> 
</body>
```

este es el de JavaScript:

```
//para validar que solo sean numeros

function solonumeros(e){


key=e.keyCode || e.which;

teclado=String.fromCharCode(key);

numeros="0123456789";

especiales="8-37-39-46";

tecla_especial=false;

for (var i in especiales){
if (key==especiales[i]) {
    tecla_especial=true;
}
}

if (numeros.indexOf(teclado)==-1) {
return false;
}
}

 //para asignar cada valor
 function retornar(num){
   var anterior=document.fo.valores.value;
   document.getElementById("valores").value=anterior+num;

 }


 //para eliminar el ultimo caracter


 // para eliminar todo


 //para realizar todas las operaciones


 //para validar lo signos
```

Comment: Hola Juan Diego, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y así ganar tu primera medalla). Aunque esta pregunta es interesante y se ajusta bien a la temática del sitio, deberías editarla para añadir más información: ¿qué es lo que no funciona? ¿Qué tutorial estás siguiendo? ¿Recibes algún error en la consola? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información y recomendaciones de mejora. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

He modificado la función `retornar` para que te funcione lo que tienes ahora mismo. El problema es que estabas usando `document.fo.valores.value`, que no se muy bien cual era tu intención, pero añadiendo esta modificación ya deberían aparecerte los números en pantalla.

A demás, también estabas cerrando mal las etiquetas `<tr>` de la tabla, y te faltó cerrar la etiqueta `<html>`.

```js
//para validar que solo sean numeros

function solonumeros(e){

  key=e.keyCode || e.which;

  teclado=String.fromCharCode(key);

  numeros="0123456789";

  especiales="8-37-39-46";

  tecla_especial=false;

  for (var i in especiales){
    if (key==especiales[i]) {
      tecla_especial=true;
    }
  }

  if (numeros.indexOf(teclado)==-1) {
    return false;
  }
}

 //para asignar cada valor
 function retornar(num){
   //var anterior=document.fo.valores.value;
   var valores = document.getElementById('valores');
   valores.value = valores.value + num;
 }


 //para eliminar el ultimo caracter
 

 // para eliminar todo


 //para realizar todas las operaciones


 //para validar lo signos
```

```css
input[type=button],input[type="text"]{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 font-size: 30px; 
}
table,form{
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Calculadora Basica en javascript </title>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="Fo">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5"><input type="text" name="valores" id="valores" onkeypress="return"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="7" onClick="retornar(value)"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="8" onClick="retornar(value)"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="9" onClick="retornar(value)"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="+"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="-"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="4" onClick="retornar(value)"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="5" onClick="retornar(value)"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="6" onClick="retornar(value)"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="*"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="/"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="1" onClick="retornar(value)"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="2" onClick="retornar(value)"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="3" onClick="retornar(value)"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="<-"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="C"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="0" onClick="retornar(value)"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="="></td>
      </tr>
    </table>    
  </form> 
</body>
</html>
```